# Are there any databases that use delta or diff-based replication?

Tags: database, replication, delta

Are there any databases that use a delta-based replication system instead of an oplog or binlog style replication scheme? I'm looking for examples of current systems, plugins to existing databases (mysql, postgresql, mongodb, etc) or specialized databases of limited functionality.

Specifically, I'm looking for systems that reduce replication by sending changes every few seconds instead of constantly sending information about every update.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge. The closest you will come is with something like [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) which replicates at the disk block level, rather than at the application level.